# Default rule severity in SonarQube Web Service API?

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to get information about a rule's default severity (the one that is set by the language plugin) through the Web Service API?

[image: Default rule severity]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `api/rules/search` to get this data. You'll find the default severity in the "severity" field. To also get activated severity per profile, add `activities` to your `f` (field list) parameter value.

Comment: How is the severity for a rule within a profile defined if this field represents default severity?

Comment: See my expansion @Alix